# detecting command not found in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a series of command to execute. However I need to exit whenever 'command is not found' error occurs. So post execution check of output is not an option

The "$?" variable is equal zero when 'command is not found' and on success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a program exists from a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this should be done from a script, it's natural to use a conditional to express this kind of behaviour:

```
asdf 2> /dev/null || exit 1
```

Comment: this is actually the most simple and and clean way, ty

Comment: How about `ls /this/file/does/not/exist 2>/dev/null` ? ls command still exists.

Comment: @anishsane Of course. No one said that this would exclude other cases of command failures.

Comment: +1! I did not know that it is working even if the called program not exists.Thx!

Answer (score 6):

If the command is not found, the exit status should be 127. However, you may be using `bash` 4 or later and have a function called `command_not_found_handle` defined. This function is called if a command cannot be found, and it may exit 0, masking the 127 code.

Running `type command_not_found_handle` will show the definition of the function if it is defined. You can disable it by running `unset command_not_found_handle`.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

Try

```
[ -x "$executable" ] && echo "Command '$executable' not found" >&2 && exit 1
```

This will write an error to stderr and exit with 1 exit code.

If You have just the name of the utility You can check its path with `type` build-in.

Example:

```
type type
type ls
type xls
```

Output:

```
type is a shell builtin
ls is /usr/bin/ls
./test.sh: line 13: type: xls: not found
```

Test returns 1 if utility not found.

So if the `$executable` can be anything (a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) build-in, alias, binary, ...), then this could be used:

```
type -p ls>/dev/null && ls -l
type -p xls>/dev/null && xls --some_arg
```

This will run `ls` (any executable), but not xls.

Anyway if in the script the `execfail` option is not set (`shopt`) then the script will exit after stating the `bash: some_utility: command not found` error message. If this option is set, then it continues. But You can `trap` the pseudo signal `ERR` and do what You need:

```
shopt -s execfail
fnc() { echo $?, $_, Oops;}
trap fnc ERR

ls -d *|head -2
xls
yls
```

Output:

```
a1
a2
./test_tLcn.sh: line 8: xls: command not found
127, xls, Oops
./test_tLcn.sh: line 9: yls: command not found
127, yls, Oops
```

Comment: This will only work if `$executable` is a path to the executable you are looking for. `-x` does not perform path lookups.

Comment: @chapner: You are right! It does not detect internal bash commands. It could be done with e.g. `type`.

Comment: @chapner: I updated my answer according your comment. Pls take a look at it!

Comment: Trapping `ERR` seems overly broad, since that function will run on *any* error, not just a command-not-found error.

Comment: @chepner: Yes. But if `$?` is 127 then it can be detected that the command-not-found error occurred. `$_` can be used to print the not found utility.

Answer (score 0):

Take `jq` as an example:

```bash
jq --version || echo "Please install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download) first." &&  exit 1
```