# when command not found, bash `$?` return 0, not 127

Tags: bash

I have a shell script file, I check the $? is 0 to judge the script run successfully.

When the script has a error command, it will run failed, I think it will exit by 127, but if I use `bash -l` it still return 0, this make me dont know there is running successfully or command not found. BUt if no `-l` it return 127

there is my demo:

```
[root@T /tmp]# cat _script.sh
no_such_cmd
[root@T /tmp]# bash _script.sh
_script.sh: line 1: no_such_cmd: command not found
[root@T /tmp]# echo $?
127
[root@T /tmp]# bash -l _script.sh
no_such_cmd : command not found
[root@T /tmp]# echo $?
0
[root@T /tmp]# no_such_cmd
no_such_cmd : command not found
[root@T /tmp]# echo $?
0
[root@T /tmp]# zsh
[root@T]/tmp# no_such_cmd
zsh: command not found: no_such_cmd
[root@T]/tmp# echo $?
127
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce; I get the exact same error message and exit status for both `bash _scrip.sh` and `bash -l _script.sh`.

Comment: I suspect your shell init file (~/.bash_login, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.profile) sets up something that runs automatically between interactive commands (e.g. a debug trap, PROMPT_COMMAND, or something similar), and the exit status from that is replacing that from the failed command. Try adding `set -x` to the script, and see what that shows.

Comment: @GordonDavisson
 
    [root@T /tmp]# set -x _script.sh
    +++ history 1
    +++ read x y
    +++ echo 2017-04-13 10:14:15 set -x _script.sh
    ++ z='2017-04-13 10:14:15 set -x _script.sh'
    +++ date +%c
    ++ echo -n '[' Thu Apr 13 10:14:15 2017 ']'
    +++ who am i
    ++ echo -n '[' root pts/4 Apr 12 18:59 '(10.123.138.138)' ']'
    ++ echo '[' 2017-04-13 10:14:15 set -x _script.sh ']'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the answer of @chepner in [detecting command not found in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918272/detecting-command-not-found-in-bash-script)

and add the `unset command_not_found_handle` at the first line has solved the matter

Answer (score 0):

A snippet of code would help with a diagnosis.  I'm running a very old version of bash (3.2.25) and I can't duplicate your results.

```
$ a
-bash: a: command not found
$ echo $?
127
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

But as previously stated, check if the command exists first.  `command -v` might be what you're after.

Comment: I checked agian,  the bash version Has nothing to do with this matter，all of the error cmd on my machine exit by 0

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can check the command exists *before* trying to call it: [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script?rq=1)