# capture all bash commands as parameters for a custom runner

Tags: bash

I have a custom 'runner'-script that I need to use to run all of my terminal commands. Below you can see the general idea in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running '$@'"
# do stuff before running cmd
$@
echo "Done"
# do stuff after running cmd
```

I can use the script in bash as follows:

```
$ ./run.sh echo test
Running 'echo test'
test
Done
$
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
$ echo test
Running 'echo test'
test
Done
$
```

Bash has the `trap ... DEBUG` and `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which lets me execute something *before* and *after* a command, but is there something that would allow me to execute *instead* of the command?

There is also the `command_not_found_handle` which would work if I had an empty `PATH` env variable, but that seems too dirty.

Comment: As an aside, you are missing obligatory quotes around `"$@"`. Without the double quotes, your code is broken - it cannot handle quoted arguments correctly.

Comment: If the purpose of your script is to run arbitrary code, then this is the case where you *should* use `eval`. Just use `eval "$1"` instead of `"$@"`, and run the script as `./run.sh 'echo test'` instead. (And make sure that the string you pass to the script is properly quotes, e.g., `./run.sh 'echo "This is an asterisk: *"'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detecting command not found in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918272/detecting-command-not-found-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I ended up looking at the source code and found that bash does not support custom executors. Below is a patch to add a new handle that works similarly as the `command_not_found_handler`.

```
diff --git a/eval.c b/eval.c
index f02d6e40..8d32fafa 100644
--- a/eval.c
+++ b/eval.c
@@ -52,6 +52,10 @@
 extern sigset_t top_level_mask;
 #endif

+#ifndef EXEC_HOOK
+#  define EXEC_HOOK "command_exec_handle"
+#endif
+
 static void send_pwd_to_eterm __P((void));
 static sighandler alrm_catcher __P((int));

@@ -172,7 +176,15 @@ reader_loop ()
              executing = 1;
              stdin_redir = 0;

-             execute_command (current_command);
+             SHELL_VAR *hookf = find_function (EXEC_HOOK);
+              if (hookf == 0) {
+                  execute_command (current_command);
+              } else {
+                  char *command_to_print = make_command_string (current_command);
+                  WORD_LIST *og = make_word_list(make_word(command_to_print), (WORD_LIST *)NULL);
+                  WORD_LIST *wl = make_word_list(make_word(EXEC_HOOK), og);
+                  execute_shell_function (hookf, wl);
+              }

            exec_done:
              QUIT;
```

One can then define `function command_exec_handle() { eval $1; }` which will be executed instead of the original command given in the prompt. The original command is fully in the first parameter. The `command_exec_handle` can be given in .bashrc and it works as expected.

Notice: this is very dangerous! If you mess up and put a bad command_exec_handler in your `.bashrc`, you might end up with a shell that does not execute commands. It will be quite hard to fix without booting from a live cd.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you have the same problem listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918272/detecting-command-not-found-in-bash-script/16918638#16918638). If you want to run some commands if your original command was not found, the Bash 4's `command_not_found_handler` will certainly fit your needs.

Try to be more specific, maybe with some code snippets that do or do not work, in order to help us to help you...